# Is the language L={words without the substring 'bb' } regular?

Tags: regex, regular-language, computation-theory

`L = {words such that the substring 'bb' is not present in in it`

Given that the alphabet is `A = {a,b}`, is this language regular? If so, is there a regular expression that represents it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this language is regular.  Since this looks like homework, here's a hint: if the string `bb` isn't present, then the string consists of lots of blocks of strings of the form `a*` or `a*b`. Try seeing how to assemble the solution from this starting point.

**EDIT**: If this isn't a homework problem, here's one possible solution:

> (a*(ba+)*b?)?

The idea is to decompose the string into a lot of long sequences of `a`s with some `b`'s interspersed in-between them.  The first block of `a`'s is at the front. Then, we repeatedly place down a `b`, at least one `a`, and then any number of additional `a`s. Finally, we may optionally have one `b` at the end. As an alternative, we could have the empty string, so the entire thing is guarded by a `?`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah i was pretty sure this was regular but its not a homework problem. A whole bunch of attempts at solutions didn't work which is why I asked. Thanks!

Comment: "lots of blocks of strigs of the form `a*` or `a*b`" might be slow (given the ambiguity of `a*a*`); how about "any number of blocks of `a*b` followed by `a*`"? (Irrelevant for the proof, but might be relevant for any actual implementation)